# Way to extract the integer values from twilio inbound sms’?

Tags: python-3.x, flask, automation, twilio-api

Would you know how to select only the int (number) variables from the inbound sms in the twilio api. At the moment all of my inbound sms' are printing in the terminal after I run this code

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse
    
app = Flask(__name__)
    
@app.route("/sms", methods=['POST'])
def sms_reply():
    """Respond to incoming calls with a simple text message."""
        
    
    from_number = request.form['From']
    to_number = request.form['To']
    body = request.form['Body']
    
        # Start our TwiML response
        
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    
        # Add a message
    resp.message("")
    print(str(body))
    return str(resp)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=70, debug=True)
```

Would you know how I could make the numbers from the body of an inbound sms a variable that I could manipulate and use. To put things into perspective, I'm trying to automate a login process that uses an OTP for authentication. I plan to use selenium to insert this code (number) I recieve through my twilio number